# What is the proper event to save data using UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, saving-data, userdefaults

I'm new to ios. I have a view controller and some data object in it. I want to save data to UserDefaults before the view controller is disappear.  In android I used "On stop" event and so on. What is the proper event in ios?

I thought about saving data everytime they change (didSet) but my data is array with 50-100 elements so may be it's not a good idea to save it every time it's changed. On the other hand, I want my data to be saved anyway - if app is destroyed and so on.

Comment: you need to override the function viewDidDisappear and try to save your data to user default there

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this function in your code**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "example")
}
```

If the app will terminate: example, **user closes the app
use this function in your `AppDelegate`**

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
     bgTask = application.beginBackgroundTask(withName:"Flink_logOut", expirationHandler: {() -> Void in
         // Do something to stop our background task or the app will be killed
     }
     // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to override this function in your view controller

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
// save data here
}
```